# Cache-Control header in firebase.json not working

Tags: json, caching, firebase, cache-control, firebase-hosting

The `Cache-Control` header in my `firebase.json` does not seem to be working. The `max-age` value for all files is set to `31536000` (1 year), but when loading the page it is still set to the browser default of `3600` (1 hour).

The `firebase.json` file seems to abide by the [firebase documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-headers)

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "public"
    },
    "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "headers": [{
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [{
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=31536000"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 24):

According to [full page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#section-full-firebasejson) configuration you have to set **hosting key** first.

This has to work:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "app",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "headers": [{
      "source" : "**",
      "headers" : [{
        "key" : "Cache-Control",
        "value" : "max-age=31536000"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: I did this for the headers and I have to hard refresh to see my index.html changes

Comment: Hi buddy to avoid this issue you can [disable your cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development) or if you are already in production but you have to do some changes in short periods you can set `max-age=3600` in this way the browser will request new data each hour.

Comment: I'm using angular 2 and my aim is to prevent my customers having to hard refresh

Comment: When I posted this I was working with react and I had the same issue because I set `max-age=31536000` then I had to change it to `max-age=172800` becaouse I was developing some features yet in this way my clients had access to my new project versions. Of course before that they have to hard refresh in order to get the new `max-age`

Comment: I set max age to 0 and they still have to hard refresh.

Comment: How can I prevent that?

Comment: @AngularM You should be using some sort of revisioning script that would append a hash (based on the file content) to each file name so the browser would know what files got changed and would request the new version. Take a look at gulp-rev for example. https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev

Comment: to fully prevent caching, use `no-store, max-age=0`

Comment: it's also still caching on my site, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to prevent caching, you should use `no-cache` and `max-age=0` together.

The no-store directive will prevent a new resource being cached, but it will not prevent the cache from responding with a non-stale resource that was cached as the result of an earlier request. Setting max-age=0 as well forces the cache to revalidate (clears the cache).

```
"headers": [{
  "source" : "**",
  "headers" : [{
    "key" : "Cache-Control",
    "value" : "no-store, max-age=0"
  }]
}]
```