# Firebase Hosting Cache + Google PageSpeed Insights

Tags: caching, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm hosting my static site on Firebase and I've included the headers key in my firebase.json file. Here's my complete config file:

```
{
   "hosting": {
      "public": ".",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json"],
      "headers": [{
         "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
         "headers": [{
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=7200"
         }]
      }]
   }
}
```

When I run a PageSpeed test with Google's PageSpeed Insights tool, I get the message:

"Leverage browser caching"

Does this mean that Firebase hosting is not applying the headers I've specified in my project config file?

Comment: Leverage Browser Caching --- I don't think so have anything to do with your hosting. This message is displayed because your website is not allowing Browser Caching which is used in making your website faster.
You can check the blogs on [PageSpeedOptimizer](https://pagespeedoptimizer.com/) for getting more insights.

Comment: I believe you need the "headers" AFTER hosting as in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39316199/5698848

Answer (score -3):

It most probably you might be missing other extensions and file types. You can control the caching in Firebase by adding following code in firebase.json

```
"source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
"headers" : [ {
  "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
  "value" : "*"
} ]
```

Reference : [How to Enable Caching with Google Firebase Hosting?](https://www.isrgrajan.com/articles/computer/how-to-enable-caching-with-google-firebase-hosting/)